# How can I tell java.beans.Introspector to ignore a getter method?

Tags: java, javabeans, introspection

I have one field which is a composition of two values. This is the field that gets serialized to/from JSON and works great.

```
public String getRevisions() { return revisions; }
public void setRevisions(String revisions) { this.revisions = revisions; }
```

I added two helper methods to retrieve the separate values, but I don't want them serialized to JSON.

```
public String getCurrentRevision() { ... return first revision ... }
public String getPreviousRevision() { ... return second revision ... }
```

Is there a way I can tell `java.beans.Introspector` to ignore these additional getters when building the `BeanInfo` via `getBeanInfo()`? An annotation would be lovely, and I'm really hoping to avoid having to manually create my own `BeanInfo` for it.

Comment: Do you have actual currentRevision and previousRevision fields? Or just the methods?

Comment: @G_H - Just the methods that return part of the actual `revisions` field.

Comment: In that case, it could be possible that the Introspector isn't gonna recognize it as a bean property anyway. I think both the field and at least one accessor/mutator with the proper name is required. Maybe run a short test to check that theory.

Comment: @G_H - The property is definitely getting serialized to/from JSON, thus my posting the question. Apparently it sees the getter and setter methods, and that's enough for it. One suboptimal solution is to rename the methods so they don't match the getFoo/setFoo pattern, but that's not ideal. I was hoping for a simple solution such as the `@Transient` annotation, and I'll accept your answer if no one posts something that works pre-Java7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this annotation from the beans API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Transient.html

They advice you to actually place it on the getter, so that seems to fit the bill.

EDIT: oops, just noticed this was introduced in Java 7. So you're gonna need to make sure this runs in a very recent JRE if you want to use it.

Comment: Bummer, we're using Java 6 though we *do* have control over the servers. Yes, this certainly looks like it would solve the problem if we can upgrade.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it, but I assume that's the ticket for Java 7.